# Como hacer para que los cambios sean permanentes?

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy aprendiendo javascript y estoy haciendo un código que al hacer clic en una etiqueta p se modifique el contenido ya existente por un textarea que luego modifica por otro texto.eso ya lo logré

El codigo que utilize fue

```
Function modificar(e) {
 G = e.getattribute('id')
Documentos.getelementbyid(G).innerHTML = "< id ='cambio' textarea></textarea> y < onclick='modificar2' button>"

Función modificar() {
Var f = Documentos.getelementbyid('cambio')
Document.getelementbyid('G').innerHTML = f
```

Ahora como hago para que el cambio sea permanente en la pagina?

Comment: Hola hackomet, ese código no es JavaScript válido, ¿por favor puedes revisar y colocar el correcto?

Comment: Por cierto, una página web no tiene ningún tipo de persistencia. lo que necesitas es almacenar los cambios en una base de datos, o en `localStorage` del navegador

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta. Voy a intentarlo hacerlo con una base de datos.PD el código no es valido por que estoy escribiendo en el teléfono y no puedo escribir muy cómodamente.

Comment: Hola, pero ahora ya puedes editarlo, arreglalo para que atraiga respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Si solo es en el navegador, prueba usar localStorage

localStorage.setItem("texto_p", "tu_texto");
document.getElementById("G").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("texto_p");